# Extract intercepts from multiple regressions in stata

Tags: stata, finance, quantitative-finance

I am attempting to reproduce the following in stata. This is a scatter plot of average portfolio returns (y axis) and predicted retruns (x axis).

[image]

To do so, I need your help on how I can **extract the intercepts** from 25 regressions into one variable? I am currently running the 25 portfolio regressions as follows. I have seen that `parmest` can potentially do this but can't get it to work with the forval. Many thanks

```
    forval s = 1 / 5 {
    forval h = 1 / 5 {
        reg S`s'H`h' Mkt_Rf SMB HML 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your data look like, but maybe something like this will work:

```
gen intercepts = .
local i = 1
forval s = 1 / 5 {
    forval h = 1 / 5 {
        reg S`s'H`h' Mkt_Rf SMB HML 

        // assign the ith observation of intercepts
        // equal to the regression constant
        replace intercepts = _b[_cons] if _n == `i'

        // increment i
        local ++i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `postfile` series of commands can be very helpful in a situation like this.  The commands allows you to store results in a separate data set without losing the data in memory.

You can start with this as a simple example.  This code will produce a Stata data set called "results.dta" with the variables s h and constant with a record of each regression.

```
cap postclose results
postfile results s h constant using results.dta, replace

forval s = 1 / 5 {
    forval h = 1 / 5 {
        reg S`s'H`h' Mkt_Rf SMB HML
        loc c = _b[_cons]
        post results (`s') (`h') (`c')
        }
    }

postclose results
use results, clear
```